# Const Auto/Identifier Errors

Tags: c++

I having trouble understanding why it won't identify this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cIiV.png)

[Rest of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FeKR.png)

Comment: Please post text as text. Images are hard for future askers to search and potential answerers to compile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is C++17 syntax. As this standard is not yet the default option for most compilers you have to tell the compiler that you are using it via the `-std=c++17` switch.

PS: you didn't say which compiler you are using, so maybe it will not support that switch or not even support C++17 at all.